# How to say "cocking a snook" in French?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

What's the translation of ["cocking a snook"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocking_a_snook) in French?

Comment: "pied de nez" seems to be translation. But it's not an often used expression in France. At least, not to describe the gesture (it has become a little obsolete), but more to describe a mockery in general (keeping why the gesture was used, and taking only its signification)

Comment: @Larme. Could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 4):

L'expression "cocking a snook" se traduirait en français par un "pied de nez".
Elle n'est plus très utilisée de nos jours, mais elle désigne toujours le même geste :
[image: un pied de nez]

C'est un geste assez moqueur, principalement utilisé par les enfants.